# Can't automatically load my efi driver on each system boot

Tags: boot, drivers, uefi, efi

I am trying to make my UEFI driver start on each boot by setting up NVRAM variables via my own program.

I've made a program that puts my uefi driver into the EFI partition on the disk and set system variables: Driver####(Driver0000 in my case) and DriverOrder. This technique worked flawlessly on virtual machine (Virtualbox, EFI Mode, Secure Boot disabled, OS: Windows 10), but does not work on real machines with pretty much any motherboard manufacturer(with secure boot disabled, Fast boot turned off). To make sure there's no problem with my efi driver, I've tried loading driver manually with efi shell ("load" command), which worked fine, but it does not work if I setup NVRAM variables on real hardware. (I am sure that the LoadOption is set up correctly). What can cause such a problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.